# Boost interprocess named_condition_any not notifying

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to switch an application over from using `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` to `boost::interprocess::file_lock` for interprocess synchronization, but when I did so I noticed that my condition variables were never being woken up.

I've created two examples that demonstrate the types of changes I made and the issues I'm seeing. In both examples the same application should periodically send notifications if invoked with any arguments, or wait for notifications if invoked with no arguments

Originally my application used `name_mutex` and `named_condition`. The below example using `name_mutex` and `named_condition` works as expected: every time the "sender" application prints out "Notifying" the "receiver" application prints out "Notified!" (provided I manually clean out `/dev/shm/` between runs).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex(boost::interprocess::open_or_create,
                                         "mutex");

  // Create condition variable
  boost::interprocess::named_condition cond(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "cond");

  while(true)
  {
    if(argc > 1)
    {// Sender
      std::cout << "Notifying" << std::endl;
      cond.notify_all();
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    else
    {// Receiver
      std::cout << "Acquiring lock..." << std::endl;
      boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::named_mutex> lock(mutex);
      std::cout << "Locked. Waiting for notification..." << std::endl;
      cond.wait(lock);
      std::cout << "Notified!" << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The following code represents my attempt to change the working code above from using `name_mutex` and `named_condition` to using `file_lock` and `named_condition_any`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_condition_any.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/file_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Second option for locking
  boost::interprocess::file_lock flock("/tmp/flock");

  // Create condition variable
  boost::interprocess::named_condition_any cond(boost::interprocess::open_or_create,
                                                "cond_any");

  while(true)
  {
    if(argc > 1)
    {// Sender
      std::cout << "Notifying" << std::endl;
      cond.notify_all();
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    else
    {// Receiver
      std::cout << "Acquiring lock..." << std::endl;
      boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::file_lock> lock(flock);
      std::cout << "Locked. Waiting for notification..." << std::endl;
      cond.wait(lock);
      std::cout << "Notified!" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However I can't seem to get the "receiver" application to wake up when notified. The "sender" happily prints "Notifying" at ~1Hz, but the "receiver" hangs after printing "Locked. Waiting for notification..." once.

What am I doing wrong with my `file_lock`/`named_condition_any` implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by a bug in the implementation of `boost::interprocess::named_condition_any`.

`boost::interprocess::named_condition_any` is implemented using an instance of `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::shm_named_condition_any`. `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::shm_named_condition_any` has all of the member variables associated with its implementation aggregated into a class called `internal_condition_members`. When `shm_named_condition_any` is constructed it either creates or opens shared memory. If it creates the shared memory it also instantiates an `internal_condition_members` object in that shared memory.

The problem is that `shm_named_condition_any` also maintains a "local" (i.e. just on the stack, not in shared memory) member instance of an `internal_condition_members` object, and its `wait`, `timed_wait`, `notify_one`, and `notify_all` functions are all implemented using the local `internal_condition_members` member instead of the `internal_condition_members` from shared memory.

I was able to get the expected behavior from my example by editing `boost/interprocess/sync/shm/named_condition_any.hpp` and changing the implementation of the `shm_named_condition_any` class as follows:

```
typedef ipcdetail::condition_any_wrapper<internal_condition_members> internal_condition;

internal_condition m_cond;
```

to

```
typedef ipcdetail::condition_any_wrapper<internal_condition_members> internal_condition;

internal_condition &internal_cond()
{  return *static_cast<internal_condition*>(m_shmem.get_user_address()); }
```

and changing all usages of `m_cond` to `this->internal_cond()`. This is analogous to how the `shm_named_condition` class is implemented.